# How to fix 500 error in AJAX and Laravel 5?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I've been stuck with a 500 (internal server error) for a long time and I don't know why. I need to pass these codes later.

**Blade**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addChirp').submit(function() {
        var msg = $('#message').val();
        console.log(msg);
        var dataString = "message="+msg;
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#showData').html(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('post', function() {
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        return var_dump(Response::json(Request::all()));
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried to change the url `post` tp something else ?

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, you can probably find the problem by checking your web server's error logs. For Apache, check `/var/log/apache/error.log`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Request` and `Response` as a global facade following

```
Route::post('post', function() {
    if(\Request::ajax()) {
        return var_dump(\Response::json(\Request::all()));
    }
});
```

If that does not work can you please update your question with full ajax response so problem can be narrowed down?

Answer (score 0):

I think you havn't added any meta value in your head tag of html like

```
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

If csrf tag exist than try modify your jax call.

```
X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').value()
```

Or, you can manually fetch and pass the value of the _token hidden field in each of your AJAX calls